pythonODBC parameters vs connectionString
I'm trying to figure out why, when I use pythonodbc.connection() parameters, the connection is successful, but when I try to do the same thing with a connection string, the connection fails. See below.
For example, this works:
driver='{FreeTDS}'
server = 'HHVDBHDSAP10'
database = 'MOAR_OMOP_CDM'
uid='domain\\uid'
pwrd=getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ')
TDSV='8.0'
port='1433'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver=driver, Server=server, Database=database, Trusted_Connection='no',
                      UID=uid, PWD=pwrd, TDS_Version=TDSV, Port=port)

But this doesn't
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        "DRIVER="+driver+
        ";SERVER="+server+
        ";DATABASE="+database+
        ";Trusted_Connection='no'"+
        ";UID="+uid+
        ";PWD="+pwrd+
        ";TDS_Version="+TDSV+
        ";PORT="+port
        )

Here's the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tmhedr3/test_sql.py", line 26, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')


Using Trusted_Connection='no' as a parameter to pyodbc.connect() is not the same thing as using ;Trusted_Connection='no' in the connection string. Have you tried using ;Trusted_Connection=no in the connection string without the single quote characters?

Just tried it, made no difference. Same error.

Actually, just solved it by removing the Trusted_Connection parameter from the connection string entirely.
